# Fatal signal 11 when using c++11 on Android(Gallxy 4s)

Tags: android, c++11, lambda, cocos2d-x

I'm making a game using cocos2d-x 2.2 and I had no problem with compiling & building c++11 stuff on xcode & ios. And also no problem with compiling & building on android project.

But the problem is I get below run-time error when trying to call c++11 feature std::function with lambda function.

11-17 00:13:38.201: A/libc(5419): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000001d0 (code=1), thread 5446 (Thread-27308)

The code is nothing special. A member variable with std::function type and saves lambda function, and is called specific timing.

What would be the problem? My test device is Gallxy 4s.

Exactly same code runs very well on ios 7 and iPhone 4.

Any advice would be great.

Edit1. Simplified code added.

```
class SimpleObject {
  typedef std::function<void (unsigned bx, unsigned by)> ClickEventHandler_t;
  ClickEventHandler_t m_click_handler;

  void SetClickEventHandler(ClickEventHandler_t handler) { m_click_handler = handler; }
};

// setup

obj->SetClickEventHandler([this](unsigned bx, unsigned by) {  TrapClicked(bx, by); });

void TrapClicked(unsigned bx, by)
{
  CCLog("Trap clicked!");
}

// call

if (m_click_handler) 
  m_click_handler(boardx, boardy);
```

Comment: Can you share the offending piece of code? "Nothing special" is a bit vague.

Comment: I added some code. I thought the code would not be the problem because it runs well in ios.

Comment: For future reference: instead of pasting your code between `<pre></pre>` tags, indent the entire code block by four spaces. You can do this quickly by selecting the entire block of code and hitting the `{}` button in the question/answer editor.

Comment: What is the android compiler you are using?  What is the lifetime of the `this` you capture in that lambda?

Comment: @Yakk / I used NDK r8e and I also tried r9b too. But both of them didn't work. Lifetime of 'this' object is like forever in the game.

Comment: same problem from 2016

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to load  a tmx map where its object items (like images & tilesets) are not in the same directory & they were referenced to my pc path. it compiled successfully with no errors by the way. so make sure that you're calling an item in the same "Resources" directory not outside it.

Comment: Well, Thanks for the tip. But its not about resource path in my case. Because it works on my iPhone and I tried lambda function without resource load.

Comment: if you could share you logcat it will be great.